# Крапка чи знак оклику при вітанні (подяці)?

Tags: пунктуація

Добрий день всім!

Ще з часів навчання в школі звикла, що вітання, наприклад, "привіт", "добрий день" й інші відокремлюються знаком оклику. Теж саме в реченнях із "дякую".

Але нерідко в діловій переписці бачу на місці знаку оклику крапку. Більш того, кілька разів чула питання, чому я вживаю там знак оклику, і один раз таке вживання було сприйнято (зовім невірно), як обурення.

Як, все ж, буде правильно? І чи варто позбутись знаків окликів взагалі при вітанні і подяці, якщо ті, хто їх читають, сприймають їх як "крик"?

Comment: Завжди радий! Можете ще тут почитати про питання: https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/259/240 У нас тут дуже вітається хороший контент, сподіваюсь, сайт знадобиться у майбутньому, і що продовжуватимете ставити питання і, можливо, відповідати на щось.

Comment: Якщо у людини з'являється подібне запитання, то людина не розуміє що таке оклик. Сама назва "Знак оклику" каже про те, коли треба використовувати цей знак.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko цей знак не обов'язково використовують, щоб виразити оклик) Наприклад, його також використовують: _"У дужках усередині цитати або після тих чи інших цитованих уривків, до яких автор хоче привернути особливу увагу, для вираження емоційного ставлення (обурення, здивування, іронії тощо або ж, навпаки, повного схвалення) до наведеного матеріалу"_ (з Правопису 2019). Випадок, про який запитує автор, хоч і стосується зовсім іншої ситуації - теж може бути винятком. Тобто і тут знак оклику не обов'язково мусить позначати оклик.

Comment: Отже ви теж не розумієте що таке оклик. Почитайте уважніше, будь ласка, що таке оклик.

Comment: Уся суть не в позначенні обурення, а в позначенні оклику під час цього обурення. Таке можливе.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Однозначну відповідь щодо того, чи *правильно* ставити знак оклику після привітання та подяки, знайти важко. У всякому разі, цей знак можна ставити після *звертання* у діловому листуванні - і тут він зовсім не означатиме крик. Думаю, цей випадок можна було би поширити також на привітання чи подяку. Детальніше - далі.

---

[Український правопис](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf) 2019 року подає нам загальне правило (п. 1 § 157 на стор. 164), за яким знак оклику ставимо:

> У кінці речення, що вимовляється з окличною інтонацією.

У [попередній версії правопису](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil5.htm#par117) це правило звучало ще лаконічніше: знак оклику ставиться:

> У кінці окличного речення.

За [Словником української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/oklychnyj) (СУМ-11):

> **Окличне речення** — речення, яке виражає емоціонально-вольові прояви того, хто говорить, і вимовляється з підвищеною інтонацією.

*Підвищена інтонація* - це необов'язково *крик*. Наприклад, у книжці "Культура ділового мовлення" Алли Коваль (1977) [йдеться](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=iNITAQAAMAAJ&q=%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5+%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83&dq=%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5+%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBov7L4-flAhUwl4sKHcLYBegQ6AEIKTAA) про вживання знака оклику при звертаннях:

> Знак оклику після звертання до службової особи вказує на те, що фактові звертання надається особливого значення.

Про обурення чи будь-яку іншу негативну емоцію тут мова не йде.

До речі, в [новіших посібниках](http://umo.edu.ua/images/content/depozitar/navichki_pracevlasht/dilove_spilkuv_1.pdf) теж є згадки про знак оклику при звертаннях в діловому спілкуванні (стор. 133):

> У діловій кореспонденції у звертанні до офіційної особи використовують
>   офіційні форми ввічливості: шановний, високошановний, вельмишановний.
>   Після звертання ставлять кому, а текст починають з малої літери. Якщо
>   ж звертання завершуються знаком оклику, текст починається з абзацу і з
>   великої літери.

Схожі міркування, а також порівняння з іншими мовами [знаходимо](http://kizman-tehn.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/SuchasniDiloviPapery.pdf) у посібнику "Сучасні ділові документи та папери" В. Садовничої 2018 року (стор. 323):

[image]

Як бачимо, для української мови характерний знак оклику після звертань - навіть у діловому листуванні. Якогось негативного забарвлення він тут не несе.

Окрім цього, якщо [довіряти](https://webpen.com.ua/pages/Morphology_constant_leng_parts/exclamation_characteristic_spelling.html) сайту "Тренажер з правопису української мови", то слова, які виражають привітання чи подяку - це вигуки. Так:

> За значенням **вигуки** поділяються на емоційні, спонукальні, застиглі
>   формули спілкування та звуконаслідувальні слова.
>
> 3. **Застиглі формули спілкування** виражають привітання, пробачення, подяку, побажання, божбу, прокльон, лайку тощо: *добридень, спасибі,
>      до побачення, на добраніч, дякую, будь ласка, прошу, пробачте,
>      вибачте, даруйте, прощайте, щасливо, помагайбі, їй-богу, чорт би його
>      взяв, хай йому грець.*

А *"коли вигук на початку речення вимовляється з окличною інтонацією, то після нього ставиться знак оклику"*.

З цього можна зробити висновок, що слова як-от "добрий день" чи "дякую" мають ознаки вигуку і можуть вимовлятися з окличною інтонацією, а значить після них можна ставити знак оклику.

Знову ж таки, однозначно ствердної відповіді на це питання дати важко і, можливо, хтось інший дійде тут інших висновків.

Comment: Дякую, дуже детальне пояснення. А чи допустимо ставити крапку після одиничного звертання на початку листа? Мені найчастіше трапляється саме такий варіант - " Добрий день, Ірино. .... ", і далі з нового абзацу вже зміст листа.

Comment: @user3471696 В [одному з джерел вище](http://kizman-tehn.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/SuchasniDiloviPapery.pdf) (стор. 323) йдеться: _"Рідше у зразках українських службових листів бачимо крапку після звертання або відсутність розділового знака."_ Це ніяк не коментовано - тобто прямо не пише, що так не правильно.

Answer (score 5):

Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови. Бусел. 2005

> **Оклик**
>
> 1. Вигук, поклик, звертання, яким привертають чию-небудь увагу.
> 2. Голосний вигук, викрик, що виражає які-небудь почуття.
> 3. Рух, жест і т. ін., яким привертають чию-небудь увагу.

Якщо на письмі потрібно позначити оклик, то використовують знак оклику.
Наприклад, коли описуються, що людина привіталася з одного боку вулиці на інший, то можливо написати:
 - Привіт!

Немає доказів того, що якщо біля привітання стоїть знак оклику, то це обов'язково означає обурення.

Comment: А чи можна ставити просто крапку?

Comment: Так, можна ставити крапку.

Comment: kaamos написала детальніше про правила.